# Getting the row ids for the checked checkboxes in jquery dataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a DataTable with one of the column is checkbox. I can select multiple checkboxes.
now on click of button i want to get row ids of selected checkboxes. Once the ajax operation is done
on click of button, i  want to select the checkboxes again for the above row ids. Basically
how to get the checked row ids and then check the checkboxes again?

Comment: Could you please post some code? - http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: It has nothing to do with database. I think Java script is enough.

Comment: sorry it was typo. Corrected to datatable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming each checkbox has the RowId as his value attribute.

Get all the selected checkboxes:

```
var selectedIds = [];

$(":checked").each(function() {
    selectedIds.push($(this).val());
});
```

Re-check the checkboxes:

```
$.each(selectedIds, function(index, id) {
    $(":checkbox[value='" + id + "']").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, is this what you are looking for,

***JQuery code***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function(){
       var dataArr = [];
       $('input:checked').each(function(){
        alert($(this).closest('tr[id]').attr('id'));// just to see the rowid's
            dataArr.push($(this).closest('tr[id]').attr('id')); // insert rowid's to array
       });
       // send data to back-end via ajax
       $.ajax({
              type : "POST",
              url : 'server.php',
              data : "content="+dataArr,
              success: function(data) {
                  alert(data);// alert the data from the server
              },
              error : function() {
              }
        });
    });
});
```

***html code***

```
<table border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr id="row1">
    <td><input id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td><input id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="2" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
    <td><input id="checkbox3" name="checkbox3" type="checkbox" value="3" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input id="btn" name="btn" type="button" value="CLICK" />
```